# What is the simplest way to draw a cylinder with a slice cut out of it with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was wondering how you would draw a cylinder with a slice cut out of it using three.js i.e. something like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7SBZ.png)

All replies are much appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is something called "constructive solid geometry". Basically it's just a way of thinking of 3D geometry as if they were solid so that you can do boolean operations such as merging and subtracting. That way you could do something like construct your cylinder, construct a wedge shape as a sort of "die", and then "cut" the wedge out of the cylinder. Here's a three.js library I've used in the past, no guarantees as to its results or efficiency though: https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get the shape you want is to extrude a `THREE.Shape` like so:

```
var settings = {
    amount: 2,
    steps : 1,
    bevelEnabled: false,
    curveSegments: 24
};

var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo( 0, 0 );
shape.absarc( 0, 0, 10, 0, Math.PI * 1.75, false );
shape.moveTo( 0, 0 );

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, settings );
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0yyg5ese/

three.js r.73

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. It is exactly what I needed but is there any way to adjust the size of the wedge somewhere else in the code?

Comment: If you are unable to answer your own question, please make a new post, show your code, and describe the issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `THREE.CylinderGeometry` and set the `thetaLength`-parameter. The default is `2 * Pi`, which makes for a complete cylinder. I have built a fiddle that looks like your Image: http://jsfiddle.net/hvgropoa/.

Downside: the slice´s faces ar missing, so you can see inside the cylinder when looking inside the cut :( However this is the simplest way, if you need a closed Cylinder I suggest doing it with `THREE.CSG`.

Answer (score 0):

After also looking for the answer, this worked out for me.

```
    // Create shape
    var cake_shape = new THREE.Shape();
    // Start from the center
    cake_shape.lineTo( 0, 0 );
    // Create an elipse 
    cake_shape.ellipse( 0, 0, 1, 1 , 0 , Math.PI * 1.75 );
    // Go back to the center
    cake_shape.lineTo( 0, 0 );
    
    // Create an extruded geometry with the previous shape, and define its 
    // depth (height of the cake)
    var cake_geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( cake_shape, { curveSegments: 10, depth: 0.5, bevelEnabled: true} );
    let cake = new THREE.Mesh(cake_geometry, cake_material);
```

[image]

Other ways such as defining a cylinderGeometry with incomplete circle just creates a pie where you can see the insides, not the wanted effect usualy.

Hope it helps future people looking for this.