# Set length of CylinderGeometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

The following code creates an object with proportional lengths.

My question is: 
*How can I set the length of one of the sides? (indicated with the red line)?*

Edit:
I'm also looking into `rectShape` but I'm not sure if I can make this into a 3d shape.

```
var shape = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( 
                new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 30, 30, 30, 7, 1 ), 
            multiMaterial );
    shape.position.set(0, 25, 0);
    scene.add( shape );
```

**Result**:

[image]

To create an image like this (top view):

[image]

Comment: you cannot do that with CylinderGeometry()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34209976/1461008 for the technique to use.